# Rails 3.2 button_to not passing GET variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

still learning rails, doing my first project.

i'm trying to pass an additional "category" variable to "new" method in my "pages" controller

```
def new
    @page = Page.new
    @cats = Cat.all
end
```

i'm doing it so the new page has already selected category from dropdown menu

it works when i use link_to

```
<%= link_to "Create new page", new_page_path(:cat => @cat.id) %>
```

but when i'm trying to use button_to

```
<%= button_to "Create new page", new_page_path(:cat => @cat.id), method: :get %>
```

the variable "cat" is not passed to "new" action view. it's not a big problem but it screws up my layout because i'm using button_to in all other places and i just hoped there is a better way to solve it that adding more css so it'll look the same

Comment: i am using https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon for nice buttons, it may works for u too

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this is to create a form with a hidden field

```
<%= form_tag new_page_path(), :method => :get do
    hidden_field_tag "cat", @cat.id
    button_to "Create new page"
end %>
```

Your version doesn't work because "button_to" method creates a form which passes params to the browser only from input fields.